# Get form's multiple inputs with the same name in spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, jsp

I have some input fields in my jsp page, and the fields can be dynamically created or removed. So I have to map the input fields to spring mvc's @ModelAttributes. But I do not know how to map input fields.

I want to submit a form that composed of:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- code omitted -->

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="content">
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="content">
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="content">
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
</form>
```

And that fields should be guided to the Java classe(@ModelAttribute):

```
package com.musicovery12.cookingstep.web.command;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class AddRecipeCommand {

    private String mainImageUrl;
    private String foodName;
    private String kcal;
    private String ingredients;
    private String foodDescription;

    // I do not know how to map into this field.
    private List<RecipeStep> recipeSteps;

    private String videoUrl;


    public String getMainImageUrl() {
        return mainImageUrl;
    }
    public void setMainImageUrl(String mainImageUrl) {
        this.mainImageUrl = mainImageUrl;
    }
    public String getFoodName() {
        return foodName;
    }
    public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
        this.foodName = foodName;
    }
    public String getKcal() {
        return kcal;
    }
    public void setKcal(String kcal) {
        this.kcal = kcal;
    }
    public String getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }
    public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
    public String getFoodDescription() {
        return foodDescription;
    }
    public void setFoodDescription(String foodDescription) {
        this.foodDescription = foodDescription;
    }
    public List<RecipeStep> getRecipeSteps() {
        return recipeSteps;
    }
    public void setRecipeSteps(List<RecipeStep> recipeSteps) {
        this.recipeSteps = recipeSteps;
    }
    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }
    public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddRecipeCommand [mainImageUrl=" + mainImageUrl + ", foodName="
                + foodName + ", kcal=" + kcal + ", ingredients=" + ingredients
                + ", foodDescription=" + foodDescription + ", recipeSteps="
                + recipeSteps + ", videoUrl=" + videoUrl + "]";
    }
}
```

That command class has a property that is not primitive type. It's RecipeStep:

```
package com.musicovery12.cookingstep.web.command;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class RecipeStep {
    private String content;
    private MultipartFile image;

    public RecipeStep() {}

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public MultipartFile getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(MultipartFile image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RecipeStep [content=" + content + ", image=" + image + "]";
    }


}
```

So my question is, 
how to map the form's input fields into the above java class?
is it possible by changing the name of input fields? then, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MultipleFileUploadForm {
 
    private List<MultipartFile> files;
 
        public List<MultipartFile> getFiles() {
            return files;
        }
 
        public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {
            this.files = files;
        } 
 
}

public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute("multipleFileUploadForm") MultipleFileUploadForm multipleFileUploadForm){

}
```

Add the `@ModelAttribute` in the controller

Comment: I did it. it was because of typo on form tag's enctype in JSP. and I can get the fields' value by naming field[0] field[1] field[2] field[n].